# why there is no graalvm apt source

Tags: java

I like ubuntu because of apt and easy installation, but we do not have graalvm in sources, do you know why ?

Graalvm is open source https://github.com/graalvm and there is [mandrel](https://github.com/graalvm/mandrel) which is targetting quarkus, and I was planning to test spring native on my ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time some hero decided to make the deb. https://github.com/dongjinleekr/graalvm-ce-deb

here is apt source https://github.com/dongjinleekr/graalvm-ce#how-to-use

Answer (score 5):

Nobody has yet volunteered their time and effort to package this software for Debian.

Once packaged properly in Debian, the software will sync to the next Ubuntu release.

If you want to volunteer to learn how to package software using the Debian method (that means you use apt to install/remove it), start your journey at http://mentors.debian.net